# QT No such file or dictionary when I try to include a header file

Tags: c++, c, qt-creator

This is a very common issue in QT. Include header files and then get the error.

```
No such file or directory
```

**How to reproduce the issue:**

1. First I'm using the CAN Bus Open SAE J1939 library
2. Then I include the source and headers like this.

   ```
   SOURCES += \
    Communication/Database/databasehandling.cpp \
    Tool/Json/jsonhandling.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    Window/Main/mainwindow.cpp \
    Communication/USB/usb.cpp \
    Tool/CAN/Hardware/CAN_Network/CAN_Network.c \
    Tool/CAN/Hardware/Memory/FLASH_EEPROM_RAM_Memory.c \
    Tool/CAN/ISO_11783/ISO_11783-7_Application_Layer/Auxiliary_Valve_Command.c \
    Tool/CAN/ISO_11783/ISO_11783-7_Application_Layer/Auxiliary_Valve_Estimated_Flow.c \
    Tool/CAN/ISO_11783/ISO_11783-7_Application_Layer/Auxiliary_Valve_Measured_Position.c \
    Tool/CAN/ISO_11783/ISO_11783-7_Application_Layer/General_Purpose_Valve_Command.c \
    Tool/CAN/ISO_11783/ISO_11783-7_Application_Layer/General_Purpose_Valve_Estimated_Flow.c \
    Tool/CAN/Open_SAE_J1939/Listen_For_Messages.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-21_Transport_Layer/Acknowledgement.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-21_Transport_Layer/Request.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-21_Transport_Layer/Transport_Protocol_Connection_Management.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-21_Transport_Layer/Transport_Protocol_Data_Transfer.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-71_Application_Layer/Request_Component_Identification.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-71_Application_Layer/Request_ECU_Identification.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-71_Application_Layer/Request_Software_Identification.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-73_Diagnostics_Layer/DM1.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-73_Diagnostics_Layer/DM2.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-73_Diagnostics_Layer/DM3.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-73_Diagnostics_Layer/DM14.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-73_Diagnostics_Layer/DM15.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-73_Diagnostics_Layer/DM16.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-81_Network_Management_Layer/Address_Claimed.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-81_Network_Management_Layer/Address_Delete.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-81_Network_Management_Layer/Address_Not_Claimed.c \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-81_Network_Management_Layer/Commanded_Address.c

   HEADERS += \
    Communication/Database/databasehandling.h \
    Tool/Json/jsonhandling.h \
    Window/Main/mainwindow.h \
    Communication/USB/usb.h \
    Tool/CAN/Hardware/CAN_Network/CAN_Network.h \
    Tool/CAN/Hardware/Memory/FLASH_EEPROM_RAM_Memory.h \
    Tool/CAN/Hardware/Processor_choice.h \
    Tool/CAN/ISO_11783/ISO_11783_Enums/Enum_Auxiliary_And_General_Purpose_Valves.h \
    Tool/CAN/ISO_11783/ISO_11783-7_Application_Layer/Application_Layer.h \
    Tool/CAN/Open_SAE_J1939/Open_SAE_J1939.h \
    Tool/CAN/Open_SAE_J1939/Structs.h \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939_Enums/Enum_Control_Byte.h \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939_Enums/Enum_DM1_DM2.h \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939_Enums/Enum_DM14_DM15.h \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939_Enums/Enum_Group_Function_Value.h \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939_Enums/Enum_NAME.h \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939_Enums/Enum_PGN.h \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939_Enums/Enum_Send_Status.h \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-21_Transport_Layer/Transport_Layer.h \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-71_Application_Layer/Application_Layer.h \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-73_Diagnostics_Layer/Diagnostics_Layer.h \
    Tool/CAN/SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-81_Network_Management_Layer/Network_Management_Layer.h
   ```

But still I get one error in the `Transport_Layer.h` file

```
#ifndef SAE_J1939_21_TRANSPORT_LAYER_SAE_J1939_21_TRANSPORT_LAYER_H_
#define SAE_J1939_21_TRANSPORT_LAYER_SAE_J1939_21_TRANSPORT_LAYER_H_

/* Layers */
#include "../../Hardware/CAN_Network/CAN_Network.h"
#include "../../Open_SAE_J1939/Structs.h"
#include "../SAE_J1939-71_Application_Layer/Application_Layer.h"
#include "../SAE_J1939-73_Diagnostics_Layer/Diagnostics_Layer.h"
#include "../SAE_J1939-81_Network_Management_Layer/Network_Management_Layer.h" <--- This one
#include "../SAE_J1939_Enums/Enum_Control_Byte.h"
#include "../SAE_J1939_Enums/Enum_DM1_DM2.h"
#include "../SAE_J1939_Enums/Enum_DM14_DM15.h"
#include "../SAE_J1939_Enums/Enum_Group_Function_Value.h"
#include "../SAE_J1939_Enums/Enum_NAME.h"
#include "../SAE_J1939_Enums/Enum_PGN.h"
#include "../SAE_J1939_Enums/Enum_Send_Status.h"
```

And one inside `Application_Layer.h` file

```
#ifndef ISO_11783_ISO_11783_7_APPLICATION_LAYER_ISO_11783_7_APPLICATION_LAYER_H_
#define ISO_11783_ISO_11783_7_APPLICATION_LAYER_ISO_11783_7_APPLICATION_LAYER_H_

/* Layers */
#include "../../Hardware/CAN_Network/CAN_Network.h"
#include "../../ISO_11783/ISO_11783_Enums/Enum_Auxiliary_And_General_Purpose_Valves.h" <-- This one
#include "../../Open_SAE_J1939/Structs.h"
#include "../../SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-21_Transport_Layer/Transport_Layer.h"
#include "../../SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939_Enums/Enum_PGN.h"
```

**Question:**

Why does this happening?
I have included. The QT Creator IDE sees the files. No problem there. But still, the compiler seems not to understand the existens of these files.

I'm using QT 5.15.2 and C++11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. You don't need the `.pri` file as shown in an answer here. Get rid of it.

Here is what I have done.

1. Right click on your project in QT.
2. Select "Add existing dictionary"
3. Mark the dictionary you want to import. Now you are seeing lots of `.c` and `.h` files inside the `.pro` file.

Hint: Don't use `../../`, that can cause troubles. Instead use the project path instead e.g

```
"ThirdLibrary/OpenSAEJ1939/...your_h_files.h"
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

With the little information that the OP provides, I cannot point out the cause of the error, but when I add third-party libraries to my projects, then it is better to create a .pri that includes what is necessary to link the project. In this case:

```
├── 3rdParty
│   └── OpenSAEJ1939
│       ├── Hardware
│       ├── ISO_11783
│       ├── LICENSE
│       ├── Open_SAE_J1939
│       ├── OpenSAEJ1939.pri
│       └── SAE_J1939
├── 68795702.pro
└── main.cpp
```

***.pro**

```cpp
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

include(3rdParty/OpenSAEJ1939/OpenSAEJ1939.pri)
```

**OpenSAEJ1939.pri**

```cpp
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

#include <ISO_11783/ISO_11783-7_Application_Layer/Application_Layer.h>
#include <Open_SAE_J1939/Open_SAE_J1939.h>
#include <SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-71_Application_Layer/Application_Layer.h>
#include <SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-73_Diagnostics_Layer/Diagnostics_Layer.h>
#include <SAE_J1939/SAE_J1939-81_Network_Management_Layer/Network_Management_Layer.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    /* Create our J1939 structure with two ECU */
    J1939 j1939_1 = {0};
    J1939 j1939_2 = {0};

    /* Important to sent all non-address to 0xFF - Else we cannot use ECU address 0x0 */
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 255; i++){
        j1939_1.other_ECU_address[i] = 0xFF; /* 0xFF is the broadcast address */
        j1939_2.other_ECU_address[i] = 0xFF;
    }

    /* Set the ECU address */
    j1939_1.this_ECU_address = 0x80;                                                /* From 0 to 253 because 254 = error address and 255 = broadcast address */
    j1939_2.this_ECU_address = 0x90;

    QWidget widget;
    widget.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

<sub>You can find the full demo [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/68795702).</sub>

Comment: Hmm...only the headers gets included, but not the sources.

Comment: @MrYui Do you understand how projects are compiled? Have you read the README of the project(in special step 4)?

Comment: I did the same thing as you did.

Comment: @MrYui Have you tried the demo I have provided? First test that demo (I have done it and it works), and if it works for you then my work is over and yours begins, which is: how to integrate it into your project

Comment: No, I haven't try your examples. But I seems that the source files cannot be found. I can see the header files and go into them, but when I click on the functions inside the header files, then nothing happens. It says that source files are missing.

Comment: By the way. Cool repository. Why are you save these at your git? :)

Comment: @MrYui It seems that you do not understand, the compiler is different from the editor, according to what you point out to me, the editor cannot find it but if the compiler does, or are you going to modify the .c, .cpp of 3rdparty library? Well no, then they don't need to be visible. Please try the demo as I have followed the README manual, and you don't seem to. Goodbye. GIT: Let me keep some long sample demos.

Comment: Do I have to modify the .c files to .cpp? I tried your example. Same issue there as well.

Comment: @MrYui What does: *Nope, did not work at all* mean? If you want more help then you must provide feedback. Saying that it does not work without noting in detail why it does not work does not help us to understand the error.

Comment: Well, I tried out your example. Same issue as I have. So I guess the QT Creator IDE cannot read .c files?

Comment: @MrYui Have you downloaded all my demo files? Well, I don't know what else to say, bye.

Comment: Yes, I have downloaded the "demo" files.

Comment: Try to open "void Open_SAE_J1939_Listen_For_Messages(J1939 *j1939);" and see if you can see the .c file.

Comment: @MrYui I already told you that it is not necessary to show the .c, obviate the warnings of the IDE, just press the "RUN" button.

Comment: Really? `undefined reference to `Open_SAE_J1939_Listen_For_Messages'` It's a warning. But I assume that you don't know. That's OK. I can ask QT forum.

Comment: @MrYui In simple words: The project is not structured correctly (perhaps it is a bug that you have to report in that project) for Qt Creator to review the .c. Bye

Comment: Solved the problem now.